# Prevent a user from selecting a particular dropdown option in Google Sheets

Tags: permissions, google-sheets

I have a drop down list in a Google Sheet that lists people's email addresses.

Is there a Google Script which will only let the user select their own email address and no one else's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It uses onEdit and if A1 (dropdown email list) on Sheet1 is edited, it compares the user to the selected email from the list. Copy and paste into the Script Editor:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var userEmail=e.user
 var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
 var editedCell = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
 var selectedEmail= e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()
 if(sheet=="Sheet1" && editedCell=="A1"){
  if(selectedEmail==userEmail){
    return}
  else{
    Browser.msgBox('Must select your email.')
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1").clearContent()
    }
}}
```

Comment: I'll give it a crack! How can I build a function into this where admins have access to all email addresses?

Comment: Add another if statement after the first one. If (e.user=="admin email address "){return}

Comment: This works for producing the comment box, however the sheet will still calculate depending on what the input in A1 is. Is there a way to put in a function that prevents any calculations if access is denied?

Comment: If you will share a sample spreadsheet showing what you are doing, I will see what I can do.

Comment: I added a line to clear the dropdown content. Depending on what you are doing, this may solve your problem. See revised code.